# Best way to load data from MySQL with PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, database

Looking at other questions, none seem to be specific enough for my case.  I am creating a blog-like website and have created a user-authenticated page that allows me to add a title, main content, and image using a form that is sent to a php file that stores the data in the mySQL database.  Then, the php redirects me to the index page where I want to load the latest blog post along with all previous posts and put them in a div with styling.  I do not think I need AJAX for this. I only need the data to load per each visit, therefore, is the best thing for me to do is to call a javascript function on $(document).ready() that will access the data in the database? If so, how can I implement PHP in my javascript to work with the database and then store the info in javascript variables.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly don't need AJAX for this. Just use your index.php page to look up the blog posts in the db and then loop through and echo them out.

You could later incorporate AJAX to call a php page which would provide the blog posts to you. This way you could update the page after it is loaded when new blog posts are created.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you do not seem to have a firm grasp on the role of each language. If you're building something on your own follow the advice of someone who has built ALL of it and can show it off to boot (see my profile, my site contains a blog, forums, private messaging, chat room, CMS, etc all built entirely by myself using no one else's code).

(X)HTML - It's the noun language, an image, a paragraph, a division element used by CSS to style the page, etc.

CSS - The adjective language, describes how the (X)HTML noun language is displayed.

JavaScript - The verb language, event driven; when the user does (onmouseover, onclick, onload, etc) action execute this code (usually a function). AJAX is simply loading content after the page has finished loading. You can worry about the fancy stuff once you have your basics working.

PHP - Server side language, prepares code (mostly XHTML) to be sent to the client's computer.

Database - Where your content is stored.

"$(document).ready() " is not JavaScript, that's jQuery. If you want to learn stay as far away from JavaScript libraries and learn REAL JavaScript otherwise you're going to run in to the nightmares associated with it (crap performance versus native JavaScript, updating libraries changes how you must code to them, etc). Feel free to look at my site's source code as it's all written for XHTML as application/xhtml+xml which means it WILL work in regular HTML though the vast majority of sites do NOT work if you switch them to XHTML. In other words when you code right the first time you'll have much more confidence that it will JUST WORK end of story. People don't care about how you did it but that it works and if it ALWAYS works then they simply can't get any happier with what they have.

---

If you're building the main blog page you simply need a single SQL query to pull all the content. My blog I programmed to display the last eight latest blog entries though with my pagination it's exactly like a book, the first page (on the left side) starts with the first eight, so if the count isn't divisible by eight you might see six entries on the latest page.

When using SQL you want to CONSTRUCT your query, NEVER stick it inside of a loop! The fewer queries you execute the better your code is and the better your performance. I recommend downloading MySQL Workbench and setting up a MySQL query log and then use Tail for Win32 to view queries in real time to see what your code is doing.

Apache also has logs. You are building this LOCALLY at http:// localhost/ first correct? You should never test something live until you've exhausted testing it locally first. See my base element blog entry about how to best do that...

http://www.jabcreations.com/blog/streamlining-local-and-live-development-with-the-base-element

---

If you're talking about redirects keep the technical stuff hidden from users and take advantage of $_SESSIONS in PHP. Record what the current page URL is (relative to the base which is different for local/local network/live environments), have a second-URL to fall back to and if that too matches the redirect page then have a safe-URL that is statically defined. If you're constantly falling back to the static URL then check to make sure you haven't goofed up how your other two variables are being updated each page load (such as not updating it if you're on the redirect page obviously).

---

When you solidify your basic understanding you will want to ask very specific questions as your question is wildly subjective and to most programmers not really worth answering. Make sure you use correct terminology, stick to core languages and not libraries as doing so will help ensure your working code will last that much longer. The stricter your coding practices the better off you'll be. Maximize the sensitivity of your error reporting for HTTP, JavaScript, PHP and SQL errors. Getting PHP is not set errors? What if a hacker is trying to pry error messages from your code? Make sure those variables are set before you even begin to start working with them. Log your errors and fix them fanatically. Don't try to add every feature in the world, concentrate on the critical functionality first and make sure it's incontestably solid before you expand upon it. Do these things and while it may take more time up front you will be rocking harder than the vast majority of people drowning in live environments that are built on not solid code.

Comment: I do know the differences. And if you would read my post clearly you would see that I was not referring to the JQuery $(document).ready() function as Javascript. I said "call a javascript function on $(document).ready()" as in the call stack. I simply am asking for the best method to load the data from my DB onto my page...

Answer (score 0):

gizmovation is right, you don't need AJAX, but to answer the question "how can I implement PHP in my javascript to..."

You're looking to use AJAX.  Use jQuery's .ajax to call the PHP page, and when it returns the result, put it into the javascript variables, or directly into the DOM.  [AJAX example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) or [jQuery example](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)